# Merge existing dataframe into fixed size new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe which looks like below

```
print "Key", IRI_KEY
print gp1[['WEEK','New_Price']]

Key 247077.0    

        WEEK  New_Price
457427  1322   3.050000
457426  1323   3.050000
457425  1325   3.340000
457429  1326   3.340000
457430  1327   3.452500
457428  1329   3.452500
457421  1330   3.340000
457419  1331   3.340000
457420  1332   3.340000


print "Key", IRI_KEY
print gp2[['WEEK','New_Price']]

Key 248244.0

        WEEK  New_Price
457550  1322      3.190
457551  1323      3.190
457549  1324      3.215
457553  1325      3.290
457554  1326      3.290
```

Then I want merge these kinds of table into new dataframe

for example in above case

```
           1322    1323    1324 ...    1373
247077.0   3.05     .....
248244.0   3.190    .....
 ...
```

so the column has week number and row has Key value.

and the contents has corresponding New_Price.

How could I merge them in that way?

Actually column size is fixed as 1322 to 1373

And there is missing on WEEK and New_Price in that case I want impute them using Auto regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into the shape you want like this:

```
>>> d = {247077.0 : gp1.set_index('WEEK'), 248244.0: gp2.set_index('WEEK')}
>>> pd.Panel(d).ix[:, :,'New_Price'].T
Out[15]:
 WEEK    1322    1323    1324    1325    1326    1327    1329    1330   1331    1332
247077   3.05    3.05    NaN     3.34    3.34    3.4525  3.4525  3.34    3.34    3.34
248244   3.19    3.19    3.215   3.29    3.29    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

In order to input the missing values with autoregression you should make a new dedicated question.

Comment: But when I try in my code I meet KeyError: 'New_Price'

Comment: @JonghoKim, take a look at the pandas documentation about the [Panel data structure](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).